# how to send mail to each person not to all together?

Tags: php, arrays, sendmail

txtTo=email1,eamil2,email3;

```
foreach (array($_POST["txtTo"]) as $v) {
    $strTo = $v; 
    $flgSend = @mail($strTo,$strSubject,$strHeader1,$strHeader); 

    if($flgSend)  
    {  
    echo "$v Mail send completed.\n<br/>";  
    }  
    else  
    {  
    echo "$v Cannot send mail.\n<br/>";  
    } 
}
```

It send email to all so I get `email1,eamil2,email3 Mail send completed.`

except of

```
email1 Mail send completed.
eamil2 Mail send completed.
email3 Mail send completed.
```

What is wrong? how to send mail to each person not to all together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the separate e-mail addresses before looping;

```
$recipients = explode(',', $_POST['txtTo']);

foreach ($recipients as $v) {
    $strTo = $v; 
    $flgSend = @mail($strTo,$strSubject,$strHeader1,$strHeader); 

    if($flgSend)  
    {  
    echo "$v Mail send completed.\n<br/>";  
    }  
    else  
    {  
    echo "$v Cannot send mail.\n<br/>";  
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that $_POST["txtTo"] is already an array, try changing this line:

```
foreach (array($_POST["txtTo"]) as $v) {
```

to this:

> foreach ($_POST["txtTo"] as $v) {

If the html input name is txtTo[] that means it is coming in as an array.

Levi